# propiedades de dos modelos no se muestran en grid con ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

tengo dos modelo(Cliente y Pago) los cuales los uno en un tercer modelo(Modelo), pero al momento de vincular los datos para mostrarlos en el grid no he podido hacer que se visualicen la información que tengo en los dos modelos, el json que regresa mi método si obtiene datos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para bindear o mostrar los datos de mi registro? ya intente colocando modelo.propiedad pero no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Modelo.Pagos',
        proxy: {
            pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
            startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
            limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
            noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"
            //storeId: 'Data',
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'Home/GetPagosAutorizados',
            // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                //record: 'Pagos',
                //record: 'Cliente'
            }
        }
    });
 

    // create the grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {        
        bufferedRenderer: false,
        store: store,
        columns: [
            { text: "ID Pago", width: 120, dataIndex: 'Pagos.IdPago', sortable: true },
            { text: "Cliente", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Cliente.Nombre', sortable: true },
            { text: "Monto", width: 125, dataIndex: 'Monto', sortable: true },
            { text: "Comisión", width: 125, dataIndex: 'Comision', sortable: true },
            { text: "Autorización", width: 125, dataIndex: 'Autorizacion', sortable: true },
            { text: "Comentario", width: 125, dataIndex: 'Comentario', sortable: true },
            { text: "Fecha", width: 125, dataIndex: 'Fecha:date', sortable: true }
        ],
        forceFit: true,
        height: 210,
        split: true,
        region: 'north'
    });
```

En el reader que esta donde se crea el store tengo

> record: 'Pagos'

y

> record:'Cliente'

cuando deshabilito cualquiera de las dos si me aparecen los datos pero solo las propiedades que pertenecen al modelo que se le asigna a `record`

Comment: Hola, si lograste solucionarlo?